# EF Core 2.1 - Handling connection on parallel async methods

Tags: ado.net, ef-core-2.1

I have multiple async methods in my DbContext to call stored procedures. All those methods handle connections as below.

```
        DbConnection connection = this.Database.GetDbConnection();
        bool needClose = false;
        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            connection.OpenAsync();
            needClose = true;
        }
        }
        try {}
        finally
        {
            if (needClose)
                connection.Close();
        }
```

I'm calling some of these methods in parallel. My connection string has MultipleActiveResultSets=True. 
I'm getting below error because the connection get closed by another method.

> Invalid operation. The connection is closed

What would be a better approach for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm closing the connection on dispose. It looks good. But if you have any other suggestions please let me know.

```
    public override void Dispose()
    {
        DbConnection connection = Database.GetDbConnection();
        if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
        base.Dispose();
    }
```